# Aggregate Function - First nvarchar in custom order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have a table with the following data:

```
TableColumnsId  AssumedDataType     Ranking
43264           System_String       1
43265           System_Int32        2
43265           System_Double       10
43266           System_Double       10
43266           System_Int32        2
43267           System_Int32        2
43267           System_Double       10
43268           System_Double       9
43268           System_Int32        8
43268           System_String       9
43269           System_String       9
43269           System_Int32        7
43269           System_Double       10
43270           System_String       5
43271           System_String       1
43272           System_String       8
43272           System_Double       4
```

I want to return only one column per TableColumnsId and the summary AssumedDataType should be the one with the lower rank.

Therefore the above data should become:

```
TableColumnsId  AssumedDataType     Ranking
43264           System_String       1
43265           System_Int32        2
43266           System_Int32        2
43267           System_Int32        2
43268           System_Int32        8
43269           System_Int32        7
43270           System_String       5
43271           System_String       1
43272           System_Double       4
```

If I use the min aggregate function with a group by it returns the first AssumedDataType alphabetically which won't work.

Comment: Is the "higher rank" the min value of ranking?, because your desired result is inconsistent. For instance, you chose the row with ranking 2 for Id 43265 (when there was another with ranking 10), but you chose the row with ranking 10 for Id 43266 (when there was another with ranking 2).

Comment: You are correct I made the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()`:

```
select TableColumnsId, AssumedDataType, Ranking
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by TableColumnsId order by Ranking) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to each group (defined by the `partition by` clause).  The ordering within the group is determined by the `order by` clause.  So, this construct assigns "1" to the row with the highest ranking for each TableColumnsId -- and the `where` clause chooses this value.

Comment: You need to remove the desc on Ranking. The lower ranking is better. It won't let me edit because it is less than a 6 char change.

Comment: @Rafi . . . I made the change.  I do want to point out that the code says "the summary AssumedDataType should be the one with the higher rank", which is why I used `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm selecting ColumnIds with the highest rank, then joining it with the main table to get DataType for that columnId and rank:

```
with Rank_cte(ColumnId,Ranking)
as(Select TableColumnsId,Min(Ranking) from TableName Group By TableColumnID)

Select A.TableColumnsId,AssumedDataType,A.Ranking From TableName A join 
Rank_cte B on A.TableColumnsId=B.ColumnId and A.Ranking=B.Ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TableColumnsId, AssumedDataType, Ranking
FROM T t1
WHERE Ranking =
    (SELECT MIN(Ranking)
    FROM T t2
    WHERE t1.TableColumnsId = t2.TableColumnsId);
```